# Replace auto filled text via userform

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform, autofill

I've developed a user form for the letters we use at work that auto fill the document after required data has been entered.

At this current point in time - when you hit OK the data will be entered and the data will fill the form. Some users are just trying to keep entering information over the top of the already filled form and stacking previously entered data into the letter.

Question: How do I get the user form to replace entered data rather than add entered data.

So if I enter the name as John Wayne, complete my letter and decide to write another letter on the same open document - how do I reopen my macro, populate the data and then overwrite all the previous information of the previous letter.

```
    Option Explicit
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim en As Boolean
    en = Not CheckBox1.Value
    EnableControls Array(TBLPGN, TBLPFN), en

    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then ComboBoxLodge.Value = "Applicant"
    If CheckBox1.Value = False Then ComboBoxLodge.Value = "Lodging parent"

End Sub


'utility sub: enable/disable controls
Private Sub EnableControls(cons, bEnable As Boolean)
    Dim con
    For Each con In cons
        With con
            .Enabled = bEnable
            .BackColor = IIf(bEnable, vbWhite, RGB(200, 200, 200))
        End With
    Next con
End Sub
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
tbForm.Value = Null
tbFN.Value = Null
tbGN.Value = Null
tbDOB.Value = Null
cbLT.Value = Null
tbPN.Value = Null
tbissue.Value = Null
tbexpiry.Value = Null
tbLTD.Value = Null
tbNarrative.Value = Null
tbPRR.Value = Null
cbRecommendation.Value = Null
CheckBox1.Value = False
ComboBoxLodge.Value = Null
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOk_Click()
    Dim useAforB As Boolean
    useAforB = CheckBox1.Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument
        .Bookmarks("Lodge").Range.Text = ComboBoxLodge.Value
        .Bookmarks("Form").Range.Text = tbForm.Value
        .Bookmarks("Form2").Range.Text = tbForm.Value
        .Bookmarks("AGN").Range.Text = tbGN.Value
        .Bookmarks("AFN").Range.Text = tbFN.Value
        .Bookmarks("LGN").Range.Text = IIf(useAforB, _
                                     tbGN.Value, TBLPGN.Value)
        .Bookmarks("RGN").Range.Text = IIf(useAforB, _
                                     tbGN.Value, TBLPGN.Value)
        .Bookmarks("LFN").Range.Text = IIf(useAforB, _
                                     tbFN.Value, TBLPFN.Value)
        .Bookmarks("RFN").Range.Text = IIf(useAforB, _
                                     tbFN.Value, TBLPFN.Value)
        .Bookmarks("DOB").Range.Text = tbDOB.Value
        .Bookmarks("LT").Range.Text = cbLT.Value
        .Bookmarks("PN").Range.Text = tbPN.Value
        .Bookmarks("PN2").Range.Text = tbPN.Value
        .Bookmarks("PN3").Range.Text = tbPN.Value
        .Bookmarks("PN4").Range.Text = tbPN.Value
        .Bookmarks("Issued").Range.Text = tbissue.Value
        .Bookmarks("Expiry").Range.Text = tbexpiry.Value
        .Bookmarks("LTD").Range.Text = tbLTD.Value
        .Bookmarks("LTD2").Range.Text = tbLTD.Value
        .Bookmarks("Narrative").Range.Text = tbNarrative.Value
        .Bookmarks("PRR").Range.Text = tbPRR.Value
        .Bookmarks("Recommendation").Range.Text = cbRecommendation.Value
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub Tbform_Change()
    tbForm = UCase(tbForm)
End Sub

Private Sub Tbfn_Change()
    tbFN = UCase(tbFN)
End Sub
Private Sub Tblpfn_Change()
    TBLPFN = UCase(TBLPFN)
End Sub

Private Sub Tbpn_Change()
    tbPN = UCase(tbPN)
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With cbLT
        .AddItem "lost"
        .AddItem "stolen"
    End With
    With cbRecommendation
        .AddItem "I believe there is an entitlement to have the l/t flag turned off as the applicant has not contributed to the loss of Passport number: "
        .AddItem "I believe there is no entitlement to have the l/t flag turned off as the applicant has contributed to the loss of Passport number:  "
    End With
    With ComboBoxLodge
        .AddItem "Lodging parent"
        .AddItem "Applicant"
     End With
     With CheckBox1
        CheckBox1.Value = True
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Public Sub AutoOpen()
    frmminute.Show
End Sub

Sub CallUF()
Dim oFrm As frmminute
  Set oFrm = New frmminute
  oFrm.Show
  Unload oFrm
  Set oFrm = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub AutoNew()
  CallUF
lbl_Exit:
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

new code currently getting a runtime error:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonOk_Click()
Dim useAforB As Boolean
useAforB = CheckBox1.Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument
    Call UpdateBookmark("Title", ComboBoxTitle.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("GN", TextBoxGN.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("FN", TextBoxFN.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("FN2", TextBoxFN.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("Street", TextBoxStreet.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("suburb", TextBoxSuburb.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("postcode", TextBoxpostcode.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("state", ComboBoxState.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("street2", .Range.Text = IIf(useAforB, _
                                 TextBoxStreet.Value, TextBoxStreet2.Value))

    Call UpdateBookmark("Suburb2", .Range.Text = IIf(useAforB, _
                                 TextBoxSuburb.Value, TextBoxSuburb2.Value))
    Call UpdateBookmark("State2", .Range.Text = IIf(useAforB, _
                                 ComboBoxState.Value, ComboBoxState2.Value))
    Call UpdateBookmark("PostCode2", .Range.Text = IIf(useAforB, _
                                 TextBoxpostcode.Value, TextBoxPostcode2.Value))
    Call UpdateBookmark("CD", TextBoxCD.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("MPN", TextboxMPN.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("MPN2", TextboxMPN.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("MPN3", TextboxMPN.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("MPN4", TextboxMPN.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("MPN5", TextboxMPN.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("MPDD", TextBoxMPDD.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("NPN", TextBoxNPN.Value)
    Call UpdateBookmark("NPDD", TextBoxNPDD.Value)
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Unload Me
End Sub

Sub UpdateBookmark(BookmarkToUpdate As String, TextAtBookmark As String)
   Dim BookmarkRange As Range
   Set BookmarkRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(BookmarkToUpdate).Range
   BookmarkRange.Text = TextAtBookmark
   ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add BookmarkToUpdate, BookmarkRange
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through your question, I realised what you wanted to do was updating the bookmark at the word document.

```
Private Sub cmdOk_Click()
   Dim useAforB As Boolean
   useAforB = CheckBox1.Value

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Call UpdateBookmark("Lodge", ComboBoxLodge.Value)
   Call UpdateBookmark("Form", tbForm.Value)
   'Do for the rest.....

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Unload Me
End Sub

Sub UpdateBookmark(BookmarkToUpdate As String, TextAtBookmark as string) 
   Dim BookmarkRange As Range 
   Set BookmarkRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(BookmarkToUpdate).Range 
   BookmarkRange.Text = TextAtBookmark
   ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add BookmarkToUpdate, BookmarkRange
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry I want to replace the entered information so people don't have to keep opening the document for blank templates.

Comment: can't you just call the macro again? I believe it will overwrite existing data

Comment: calling the macro again and entering the information just adds the new data next to the old data. I only want the new data to show - any ideas?

Comment: if that is the case clear the textbox with an empty string, i edited my answer let me know if you have any problem with it :)

Comment: So am I changing my:
`.Bookmarks("Title").Range.Text = ComboBoxTitle.Value`
to
`.frmletter4.comboboxtitle.text=`
????

Comment: You can put at the end of cmdOk_Click(). After populating the data at your word doc you can clear the textbox

Comment: Would it be possible if you tell me what is it that you would like to achieve?

Comment: Hi, I make some changes to my answer, do look into it

Comment: If I write a letter to Tom Jones, I want to be able to call the macro again and write a letter to James Paul. However when I do this currently it will just show: Mr Mr Tom James Jones Paul (as textbox fields populate bookmarks) I would like to to go from Mr Tom Jones -> Mr James Paul

Comment: Ok so to confirm: Chuck the `call updatebookmark("Title")' at the start or end of my 'cmdOk_click()` and do that for every bookmark I have eg: `Call updatebookmark("FN")` `Call updatebookmark("GN")` `Call updatebookmark("State")` etc.

and then add a new `Sub updatebookmark(Title as String)`

Comment: Put it at the end of cmdClear_Click(), if it doesn't work, let me know

Comment: one sec I put it into cmd ok.

Comment: sorry I have no idea where you want me to put this code and if im formatting this right.

Comment: add call before the function, look at the updated code

Comment: compile error: Ambiguous name detected: UpdateBookmark

Comment: Hi there is no error on my side, perhaps you would like to copy paste your code for us to see?

Comment: fixed it that one was my bad. but ding ding ding that's it! you have fixed it for me - thank you very much :)